# How to initialize empty `util.Collection[String]` in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

Can't unitialize it well, as

```
val topicAsCollection: util.Collection[String] = util.List[String]
```

isn't highlighted as an error, but compliation fails on

```
Error:(126, 59) class java.util.List is not a value
    val topicAsCollection: util.Collection[String] = util.List[String]
```

Comment: As it's a Java type, it has to be instantiated with regular Java methods. There's no companion or `apply` method to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way here is to initalize empty list the following way:

```
val topicAsCollection: util.Collection[String] = Collections.emptyList()
```

However, then it causes one more error:

This question already has answers here:

I have a code with Java collection in Scala

```
val topicAsCollection: util.List[String] = Collections.emptyList()
    topicAsCollection.add("recipes")
```

that fails in runtime

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException was thrown.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)
```

So to initalize the java ArrayList collection in scala coirrectly, the correct initialization needs the explicit type and new:

```
val topicAsCollection: util.ArrayList[String] = new util.ArrayList[String]()
```

Comment: Note that `java.util.Collections.emptyList` returns an immutable list. If these things are important for you to capture in the type system, better use the Scala collection library, not the Java one.

Comment: @Thilo unfortunately that is needed for he Java api that accepts the Java collection

Comment: You can keep `: util.Collection[String]` as the type in the last line.